# Create symbolic directory

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

How do you make a symbolic link from a directory to a directory?

I've scoured google for a straight forward answer but all examples are either for file links or kind of hand wave around how you make a directory symbolically link to another one.

Want one of those great straight up stackoverflow answers to this that will hopefully drowned out all the rest of the cruft out there.

Comment: So I guess `ln -s dir dir_link` isn't what you want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it just the same as linking to a file, `ln -s`.

```
$ mkdir testdir
$ touch testdir/file
$ ln -s testdir otherdir
$ ls otherdir
file
$
```

Comment: so the syntax is: `ln -s origin destination` ?  and sorry that was an incomplete comment I submitted on accident.

Comment: ok is `ln -s testdir/ otherdir/` different from `ln -s testdir otherdir` ? That should be my last point of confusion.

Comment: `testdir/` can have the slash(1), but if you add it to `otherdir`, it interprets that as an existing directory into which it should put the link (and fails, because it doesn't exist).  (1): It includes the slash in the link target, so it *might* not be the same on file systems that treat `/` and `//` differently; I haven't encountered any, but since configure scripts often check for it, I infer it could happen.

Comment: So I got it now. what was happening was I would try to have the slash on both. But what happens is if you put the slash on the link dir it fails because it doesn't exist of course. _But if it does exist it doesn't make a link from `real file` to `link`..._ it makes one inside of the directory of `link name` called `real file` that points to the `real file`